# Encrypt/Obfuscate file name

Tags: c#, encryption, obfuscation

I would like to store files on a shared web server but would like to hide the content of the file. I will be encrypting the contents of the file but I am very aware that if someone had the time and knowledge they could target the files based on their name.

What is the best method for either encrypting the file name or obfuscating it?

I have looked at creating a separate index file and using a Dictionary to store for the original and obfuscated file names but if I could do the same using reversible encryption that might be easier/less prone to disaster if the index file is lost.

Hope that makes sense.

Update:
To be clear I would like this to be reversible and I would like to ensure that the files are not searchable on the drive (i.e. obfuscating paths would not be sufficient).

Comment: Maybe you could do the same index idea, but using SQL?

Comment: Use a lookup table. If you encrypt it to be able to decrypt then someone else will be able to do the same.

Comment: Problem with SQL is that the allocated databases are quite small <100mb which would be enough to get started but would not work for very long otherwise that's what I would have done.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a random value to the url. Ex:

```
http://example.com/my-site/943hfkl3w7/SecretFile.zip
http://example.com/my-site/jf6490fh40/OtherFile.zip
```

This way the original file name is never changed and file locations are not guessable.

Comment: This assumes that the files are supposed to be publicly assessable. If not, then the solution is to store the files outside of publicly accessible folders.

Comment: My concern with this is that the hosting provider could theoretically search the drive for the file name or part of the file name (i.e. bank details). There is also the issue of knowing which folder the files are in, but I suppose I could hash the original folder name to get a value.

Comment: @Andy Lord - That changes my understanding of your question. You should point that out in your question above.

Comment: I did mention file name in the title but thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the RSA encryption based on a key you've generated before:

```
var provider = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.ImportParameters(RSA_KEY);

var encryptedBytes = provider.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!"), true);

string decryptedTest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(provider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true));
```

Comment: RSA encryption has a very bad performance espacially for large files

Comment: Would this work for file names? Wouldn't I need to do some additional work to account for special characters etc?

Comment: Tearsdontfalls : To encrypt the filename only it's ok don't you think ? :/

Comment: Andy Lord : Don't think you have to care about special char, but perhaps I don't really get your interogation ? But for me no, you just encrypt a byte array and then you get a string representation of it. If you are affraid of special char in the encryption result you can format to hex the encrypted byte array. 1 to 9 and A to F only.